# Dynamically adding controls from an Event after Page_Init

Tags: asp.net-2.0, page-lifecycle, dynamic-controls

Might seem like a daft title as you shouldn't add dynamic controls after Page_Init if you want to maintain `ViewState`, but I couldn't think of a better way of explaining the problem.

I have a class similar to the following:

```
public class WebCustomForm : WebControl, IScriptControl
{
    internal CustomRender Content
    {
        get
        {
            object content = this.Page.Session[this.SESSION_CONTENT_TRACKER];
            return content as CustomRender;
        }
        private set
        {
            this.Page.Session[this.SESSION_CONTENT_TRACKER] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

`CustomRender` is an abstract class that implements ITemplate that I use to self-contain a CustomForms module I'm in the middle of writing.

On the `Page_Init` of the page that holds the `WebCustomForm`, I Initialise the control by passing the relevant Ids to it. Then on the overridden `OnInit` method of the `WebCustomForm` I call Instantiate on the `CustomRender` control that's currently active:

```
if (this.Content != null)
{
     this.Content.InstantiateIn(this);
}
```

The problem is that my `CustomRender` controls need the ability to change the `CustomRender` control of the `WebCustomForm`. But when the events that fire on the CustomRender fire, the Page_Init event has obviously already gone off. So, my question is, how can I change the content of the `WebCustomForm` from a dynamically added control within it?

The way I see it, I have three options:

1. I separate the `CustomRender` controls
   out into their own stand alone
   control and basically have an aspx
   page per control and handle the
   events myself on the page (although
   I was hoping to just make a control
   I drop on the page and forget about)
2. I don't use events and just keep
   requesting the current page, but
   with different Request Parameters
3. I go back to the drawing board with
   any better suggestions anyone can
   give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with option 1. I did away with the overal control and just created separate controls that need to sit on different pages. I added properties to take Postback Urls and created Session properties for passing IDs between controls so I don't have to rely on RequestParams.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it on the InitComplete event. That's after the page has been initialized but before the state has been loaded.

Comment: Because my events will fire after the InitComplete event.